# Sesiones con archivos PHP

Tags: php

Tengo dos archivos `PHP`, en uno te pide una contraseña para poder acceder al segundo, y el segundo tiene un botón para crear una copia de seguridad. Quiero que no puedan acceder al segundo si no han ingresado la contraseña en el primero. He pensado en las sesiones php pero nosé como poder hacerlo. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Primer archivo:

```
<html lang=es dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copia de seguridad</title>
    <style>
      body{
        text-align: center;
      }

      h1{
        margin-top: 10%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Copia de Seguridad</h1>
    <h3>Introduce la contraseña</h3>
    <br>
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Entrar">
    </form>
    <?php

      $password = "12345";
      if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];
        if ($pass == $password) {
          header("Location: copiaindex2.php");
        }else {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                      alert('Contraseña incorrecta');
                      document.getElementById('pass').focus();
                    </script>";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Segundo archivo:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["copia"])){
    $dia = date("w");
    switch ($dia) {
      case '1':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia lunes realizada');
        break;
      case '2':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia martes realizada');
        break;
      case '3':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia miercoles realizada');
        break;
      case '4':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia jueves realizada');
        break;
      case '5':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia viernes realizada');
        break;
    }
  }
?>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copia de seguridad</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Copia de Seguridad</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="copiaindex2.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="copia" value="Iniciar copia">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Redactando respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar sesiones entonces debes hacer uso de [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) en ambos archivos y dejar una marca cuando la contraseña haya sido verificada:

```
<?php
/* Es importante que sea lo primero que pongas, incluso antes del HTML */
session_start();
/* Si un usuario estaba previamente validado le enviamos directamente a la segunda página */
if (isset($_SESSION['validado']) && $_SESSION['validado'] === true) {
  header('Location: copiaindex2.php');
  exit();
}
/* Las comprobaciones de seguridad deberías hacerlas antes de generar el formulario */
$password = "12345";
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
  /* No necesitas una variable intermedia */
  if ($password == $_POST["pass"]) {
    /* Marca de validación */
    $_SESSION['validado'] = true;
    header("Location: copiaindex2.php");
    /* Es importante detener la ejecución del script para evitar problemas */
    exit();
  }
}
?><html lang=es dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copia de seguridad</title>
    <style>
      body{
        text-align: center;
      }

      h1{
        margin-top: 10%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Copia de Seguridad</h1>
    <h3>Introduce la contraseña</h3>
    <br>
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Entrar">
    </form>
    <?php /* Si enviamos el formulario y llegamos hasta aquí, la clave era incorrecta */
    if (isset($_POST["enviar"])): ?>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Contraseña incorrecta');
        document.getElementById('pass').focus();
      </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

He usado la [sintaxis alternativa de los bloques de control](http://php.net/control-structures.alternative-syntax) para facilitar la lectura del código PHP junto al HTML.

En el PHP que tiene el formulario final hay que incluir estos cambios:

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Comprobamos que la marca de validación sea válida */
if (isset($_SESSION['validado']) && $_SESSION['validado'] === true) {
  if (isset($_POST["copia"])) {
    $dia = date("w");
    switch ($dia) {
      case '1':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia lunes realizada');
        break;
      case '2':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia martes realizada');
        break;
      case '3':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia miercoles realizada');
        break;
      case '4':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia jueves realizada');
        break;
      case '5':
        exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
        die('Copia viernes realizada');
        break;
    }
  }
} else {
  /* Presupongo que el primer archivo era index.php */
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
}
/* Aquí sólo llegaremos si la marca de clave correcta era válida */
?><html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copia de seguridad</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Copia de Seguridad</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="copiaindex2.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="copia" value="Iniciar copia">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y podría poner un botón después de que se ralice la copia, que se llame por ejemplo: `Copia realizada` para que cierre la sesión no? y al cerrar sesión vaya a la primera página

Comment: Sí, podrías hacerlo así haciendo uso de `session_destroy()` o bien permitir que un usuario que ha sido validado una vez pueda entrar directamente sin pasar por la contraseña mientras sea válida su sesión.

Comment: Perfecto! Ha funcionado! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Acabo de hacer una modificación para que el usuario entre directamente si su sesión sigue siendo válida

Comment: He intentado meter un botón para cerrar sesión desde de que realice la copia pero no me aparece por el `die()`

Comment: Te haré una mejora para poder incluirlo

Comment: Ya he podido hacerlo. He cambiado el `die()` por el `exit()` que son lo mismo y la creación del botón y el mensaje los he puesto antes